# I'm using List View Activity to send data to Edit Data Activity, what's the problem here?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I m retrieving item name, item description and item price from database, when user clicks on item, it will take to the edit activity where user can update or delete data, But When i click on List Item it takes me back to the Main Activity

When user clicks on view data, it displays list view
after clicking list view user should move to edit data activity, where in edit data activity data will display in edit texts boxes for update or delete

my code was running fine with one parameter item name, but when i used item description, and item price, there's this error

[image: main activity]

[image: edit data activity]

```
private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

private ListView mListView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    populateListView();
}

private void populateListView() {
    Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

    Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
    ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
    while(data.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String name = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            String des = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
            String pri = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name, des, pri); //get the id associated with that name
            int itemID = -1;
            while(data.moveToNext()){
                itemID = data.getInt(0);
            }
            if(itemID > -1){
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, EditDataActivity.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putInt("id",itemID);
                extras.putString("name",name);
                extras.putString("description",des);
                extras.putString("price",pri);
                intent.putExtras(extras);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else{
                toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
            }
        }
    });
}


private void toastMessage(String message){
    Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

new updated code, i have made the following changes

```
    package com.example.saveanddisplaysql;


    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.ArrayList;



    public class ListDataActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private static final String TAG = "ListDataActivity";

        DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

        private ListView mListView;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_data);
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
            mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

            populateListView();
        }

        private void populateListView() {
            Log.d(TAG, "populateListView: Displaying data in the ListView.");

            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
            class Model {
                String name;
                String desc;
                int price;
            }
            ArrayList< Model> listData = new ArrayList<>();

            while(data.moveToNext()){ 
            Model model = new Model();
            model.name = data.getString(1); 
            model.desc = data.getString(2); 
            model.price = data.getInt(3); 
            listData.add(model); }
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listData);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    Model model = (Model)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            String name = model.name;
            String des = model.des;
            String pri = model.pri;

            Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: You Clicked on " + name);

            Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getItemID(name, des, pri); //get the id associated with these
                    int itemID = -1;
                    while(data.moveToNext()){
                        itemID = data.getInt(0);
                    }
                    if(itemID > -1){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: The ID is: " + itemID);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(ListDataActivity.this, EditDataActivity.class);
                        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                        extras.putInt("id",itemID);
                        extras.putString("name",name);
                        extras.putString("description",des);
                        extras.putString("price",pri);
                        intent.putExtras(extras);

                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        toastMessage("No ID associated with that name");
                    }
                }
            });
        }


        private void toastMessage(String message){
            Toast.makeText(this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Logcat:**

2019-04-11 10:51:34.331 32717-32717/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2019-04-11 10:51:34.351 32717-32717/? D/TidaProvider: TidaProvider()
2019-04-11 10:51:34.364 32717-32717/com.example.saveanddisplaysql W/ReflectionUtils: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: android.os.MessageQueue#enableMonitor()#bestmatch
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:338)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethodBestMatch(ReflectionUtils.java:375)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.callMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:800)
        at miui.util.ReflectionUtils.tryCallMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:818)
        at android.os.BaseLooper.enableMonitor(BaseLooper.java:47)
        at android.os.Looper.prepareMainLooper(Looper.java:112)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

Comment: where is the error you are facing ?

Comment: did you try setting breakpoints in the onItemClick method to check which line crashes, and what the variables are set to when it does?

Comment: when i click on list view, it takes me back to main activity, instead of edit data activity

Comment: is there any problem in adapter view?

Comment: add your error log

Comment: please help us to help you..show your error

Comment: i have updated my post, check my updated code
after adding details, when i press view data, list view showing me this, and when i click on list view it takes me back to the main page instead of edit data activity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "listData" ArrayList is a String type array list. So you can only add Strings in it. You need to create a class like

```
class Model {
    String name;
    String desc;
    int price;
}
```

Then create array list of your model.

```
ArrayList< Model> listData = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then pass that model ArrayList to adapter and can get as well whenever needed.

Comment: phr is code ko kesy change krun?
 while(data.moveToNext()){
        listData.add(data.getString(1));
    }

Comment: Like this

      while(data.moveToNext()){
Model model = new Model();
       model.name =  data.getString(1);
       model.desc =  data.getString(2);
       model.price =  data.getInt(3);
     
       listData.add(model);
    }

Comment: There could be some syntax error in comment, please apologies. Better way is you can create constructor in the Model class and pass all three parameters together in constructor.

Comment: i changed my code, but still having the same problem :(

Comment: can you please update your new complete code? I check it

Comment: Now in new code, in your OnItemClickListener, you need to get item in this way.       

Model model = (Model)adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        String name = model.name;
        String des = model.des;
        int price = model.price;

Comment: Viewdata, showing me some garbage data in list view.. pta nhi kia masla hai, 2 din sy kr raha hun ho he nhi raha :(

Comment: can you give me your email?

Comment: asadalichoudhary@gmail.com

Comment: check my updated post, see what list view showing me now

Comment: send me your complete code and requirements, it seems there are some other issues.